# Exchange EWS API .NET - CalendarEvents.Details always null

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to build a .NET application with the purpose to retrieve Calendars information from exchanges account. I would like to retrieve free/busy information about a ressource. 
I use EWS .NET API with an Exchange 2010 connection.

I can retrieve information like the StartTime and the EndTime of an appointment but I'm not able to get other information like the subject, the location contained in the CalendarEvents.Details. Indeed this last attribute is always null. 
Apparently it could be a permission problem but it's not logical because I try to read my own calendar with my own credentials.

```
//Exchange Connection
this.service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, password, domain);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(this.email);


 List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>();

 //L'utilisateur déclaré dans l'objet, identifié par l'email
 attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo()
 {
    SmtpAddress = this.email,
    AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer
  });

 AvailabilityOptions myOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
 myOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
 myOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;


 GetUserAvailabilityResults freeBusyResults = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees,
                                                                             new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
                                                                                 AvailabilityData.FreeBusy,
                                                                                 myOptions);



  foreach (AttendeeAvailability availability in freeBusyResults.AttendeesAvailability)
        {

         foreach (CalendarEvent calendarItem in availability.CalendarEvents)
         {
             //The details here are always null :/          
            if (calendarItem.Details != null)
             {
               label3.Text = "Subject: " + calendarItem.Details.Subject +"\n";
               label3.Text += " Location:" + calendarItem.Details.Location ;
             }


             label3.Text += "\n";
             label3.Text += "Start:" + calendarItem.StartTime.TimeOfDay ;
             label3.Text += "End:" + calendarItem.EndTime.TimeOfDay;
             label3.Text += "\n";
             panel1.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
             break;       
         }
    }
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you got a solution for this? I am also hitting the same problem. Also I could find a way to set the Shape which is available in other api's where I can tell the webservice to fetch all the properties.

Comment: Just found it. The server needs to be configured to show the details. See this http://exchangeserverpro.com/show-full-freebusy-exchange-2010-room-resource-mailboxes/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, probably used the same sample code.  The problem is in your Availability Options's FreeBusyViewType

myOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.Detailed;

[Link to MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563929%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)